The contour is reduced in equal proportions
I'm using opencv's findContours() function to get the contour of the image:
contour, hierachy = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

Expectation: How to use Python to reduce the contour of the detected image in equal proportions

Hey and welcome to SO, please read the how to ask a good question and edit your question accordingly. In your case, the full code (including canny), the source image and a desired results image would be required.
